# Deactivate OK-Button if specifical field is empty

Tags: java, text, dialog, swt

I am using org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text's type of Text field. I want to deactivate the Ok-Button if a specifical textfield is emtpy.

Any ideas ?

This is my code:

```
public class CCIDDialog extends TitleAreaDialog {


  public CCIDDialog(Shell parentShell) {
    super(parentShell);
  }

  public void create(String _title, String firstchar) {
    this.firstchar = firstchar;
    super.create();
    setTitle(_title);
    setMessage("Bitte geben Sie die CCID "+firstchar+"xxxxxxx und eine Beschreibung ein (max. 7-stellig): ", IMessageProvider.INFORMATION);
    getButton(IDialogConstants.OK_ID).setEnabled(false);
  }

  @Override
  protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) {
    Composite area = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);
    Composite container = new Composite(area, SWT.NONE);
    container.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));
    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(2, false);
    container.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
    container.setLayout(layout);

    createCCID(container);
    createDescription(container);

    return area;
  }

  private void createCCID(Composite container) {
    Label lbtFirstName = new Label(container, SWT.NONE);
    lbtFirstName.setText("CCID (ohne "+firstchar+"): ");

    GridData dataCCID = new GridData();
    dataCCID.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
    dataCCID.horizontalAlignment = GridData.FILL;

    ccidText = new Text(container, SWT.BORDER);
    ccidText.setLayoutData(dataCCID);
    ccidText.setTextLimit(7);
    ccidText.addModifyListener(new ModifyListener(){

        public void modifyText(ModifyEvent e) {
           Text text = (Text) e.widget;
           System.out.println(text.getText());      
    }
    }); 
   }

  }
 }

  @Override
  protected void okPressed() {
    saveInput();
    super.okPressed();
  }
}
```

The ccidText ist the field that should not be empty.
Thank u

Comment: Yes, paste your code so far please.

Comment: Thanks, I added the code to the post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way seems to deactivate the button by default, register a modify listener on the text field which checks the text contents and activate the button if the text fields text is not empty anymore.

Comment: cool, can u explain how I can deactivate the button and add a modify listener?

Comment: ok i deactivated the Button with  getButton(IDialogConstants.OK_ID).setEnabled(false);

Comment: I tried it with the following code, but i get a ClassCast Exeption:     ccidText.addModifyListener(new ModifyListener(){
 
     public void modifyText(ModifyEvent e) {
      Text text = (Text) e.widget;
         System.out.println(text.getText());  
  }
    }); 
  }

Comment: The `ClassCastException` happens where exactly?

Comment: it was a problem from the terminal server :) now it works fine, but i have no idea how to combine two ModifyListeners for two text fields. maybe u can help again. i created a new post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22245937/how-to-compine-and-validate-two-text-fields-for-a-swt-dialog